# DNS resolver Mint inside Virtualbox doesn't work when VPN on windows host is up

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, dns, linux-mint

I have host Windows 10 with Cisco anyconnect VPN to my work net.
VirtualBox with Linux Mint.

So when Vpn on host isn't enabled everything works fine.
But when I connect vpn, my VM gets access to work net, but all other sites can't be resolved.

`VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 on` - does not helps, it works for some time but after I reboot host or guest (doesn't remember what I tried already), I can't get access to my vpn network, despite vpn is on.

As I can see dns server added in UI (8.8.8.8) appears in output: `systemd-resolve --status`

```
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (enp0s8)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (enp0s3)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 172.30.0.14
                      172.30.0.15
                      10.2.2.2
                      8.8.8.8
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      net.mycompany.ru
```

I don't know how to tell that system to try one more dns.
10.2.2.2 - is my home router - gateway, dns ip.
Can it be related with that fact that my home network uses 10.2.2.* addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found solution.
Instead of using `VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 off` and adding 8.8.8.8 dns.

I did `VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 on`, lost access to my VPN, and manually added my vpn dns server as additional via GUI.
Now looks like it works.